# Binary comprehension on Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

Is it possible and if so, how could I use binary comprehension on Elixir? I can do it on Erlang like so:

```
[One || <<One, _rest:3/binary>> <= <<1,2,3,4>>].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What in Erlang is:

```
1> [Red || <<Red:2/binary, _Blue:2/binary>> <= <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8>> ].
[<<1,2>>,<<5,6>>]
```

In Elixir is:

```
iex(1)> for <<red::8, green::8, blue::16 <- <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8>> >>, do: <<red, green>>
[<<1, 2>>, <<5, 6>>]
```

Note that the Elixir above is explicitly declaring sizes in bits, whereas the Erlang is using a type for make the calculation chop off a size in bytes. There is probably a cleaner way to do that in Elixir (at least I *hope* there is) and I might even hunt around for it -- but most of the time when I want to do this stuff extensively I stick to Erlang just for readability/universality.

**Addendum**

@aronisstav asked an interesting question: "Shouldn't there be a part matching the `green` pattern in the Erlang code?"

The answer is that there *would* be a `Green` variable in Erlang were that code to deal with bitstrings instead of binaries. [Erlang's bit syntax provides ways to indicate a few arbitrary *binary types* which correspond to default sizes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81991). Above I matched `Red:2/binary` which means I want to match a sequence of 2 bytes, and this is how we get the result `[<<1,2>><<5,6>>]`: two sequences of two bytes.

An Erlang example that is *exactly* equivalent to the Elixir code above would be:

```
[<<Red/bitstring, Green/bitstring>>
 || <<Red:8/bitstring, Green:8/bitstring, _Blue:2/binary>>
    <= <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8>> ].
```

But that is just silly to do, as Erlang's syntax for bytes is much more concise.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a part matching the 'green' pattern in the Erlang code?

Comment: @aronisstav There is, your screen may just not be showing it because the line is wide. The do-clause is: `do: <<red, green>>`

Comment: The "do..." is in the Elixir code. I am missing the matching part in the Erlang example.

Comment: @aronisstav oic. :-) The Erlang code is already matching 2 full bytes in `Red`, and so returns a binary series of two bytes. To get this behavior in Elixir I have to invent a new variable to capture it -- which is messy and why I mentioned that I prefer Erlang to Elixir when dealing with lots of binary manipulation. The unnecessarily convoluted *direct* equivalent in Erlang would be: `[<<Red/bitstring, Green/bitstring>> || <<Red:8/bitstring, Green:8/bitstring, _Blue:2/binary>> <= <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8>> ].` -- but that's just silly since Erlang handles bytes and bitstrings as needed.

Comment: I understand! Perhaps you can integrate that explanation in the answer itself, if you think it's relevant. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the documentation:

```
for << one, _rest :: binary - size(3) <- <<1,2,3,4>> >>, do: one
```